# I am building a Tab layout in my app, while debugging I keep getting this error, preventing the app from working and keeps crashing, what can I do?,

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**ERROR IN LOGCAT**
This is the error I keep getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nextview.earn, PID: 22573
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nextview.earn/com.nextview.earn.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.getTabCount()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2884)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1614)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.getTabCount()' on a null object reference
        at com.nextview.earn.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7030)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7021)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2884) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1614) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Here is the MainActivity.java, I cant find any error in the code, but when i ran it on my device, it pop us App keeps crashing
I was have tried checking youtube for solutions, but I cant find anything helpful.

**MAINACTIVITY JAVA CODE**

```
package com.nextview.earn;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    ViewPager pager;
    TabLayout mTabLayout;
    TabItem firstItem,secondItem,thirdItem,fourthItem;
    PagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        pager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

        firstItem = findViewById(R.id.firstItem);
        secondItem = findViewById(R.id.secondItem);
        thirdItem = findViewById(R.id.thirdItem);
        fourthItem = findViewById(R.id.fourthItem);


        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        adapter = new com.nextview.earn.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT,mTabLayout.getTabCount());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_read:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ReadFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_watch:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new WatchFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_click:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ClickFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**PAGERADAPTER JAVA CODE**
pageradapter.java

```
package com.nextview.earn;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final int tabsNumber;

    public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior, int tabs) {
        super(fm, behavior);
        this.tabsNumber = tabs;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new First();
            case 1:
                return new Second();
            case 2:
                return new Third();
            case 3:
                return new Fourth();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabsNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: please also share your `activity_main.xml` source code

Answer (score 0):

Verify the number of tabs in your TabLayout XML or do it but fixing a value in your Adapter

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `mTabLayout.getTabCount()` before attaching the `ViewPager` to the `TablLayout`, and passing this to the constructor of the adapter to set the no. of pages.

You need to designate this to the no. of pages you have (which is 4 in your case).

So replace:

```
adapter = new com.nextview.earn.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
    FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT,mTabLayout.getTabCount());
```

With

```
adapter = new com.nextview.earn.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
               FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, 4);
```